# Install mongodb version >3 raspberry pi 2

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is it possible to install a mongo db version greater than 3.2 on raspberry pi with RASPBIAN JESSIE LITE installed on the pi?

I only succeed to have the version 2.1 using this tutorial.

http://www.widriksson.com/install-mongodb-raspberrypi/

I tried a lot of tutorial but impossible to find one which work for greater versions.

Comment: MongoDB moved to 64bit so I'm thinking no it's not possible.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer I see that also but on mongoldb site It is written:  Starting in MongoDB 3.2, 32-bit binaries are deprecated and will be unavailable in future releases. It will be possible to install at least  3.2<

Comment: Yes you are right ! ...  I used this one,  but cant take the time to try and compile a different version. Maybe you could ... http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/

Comment: I succed in compiling  and installing mongodb from source mongo 3.0.7 using this link http://www.clarenceho.net/2015/12/building-mongodb-30x-for-arm-armv7l.html. Thanks for you help

Comment: Docker Image with MongoDB 3.0.14 [https://hub.docker.com/r/andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3/](https://hub.docker.com/r/andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3/) and [https://github.com/andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3](https://github.com/andresvidal/rpi3-mongodb3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was already written in the comments, you are limited to the 32-bit version.

Which comes with severe drawbacks:

- The data which can be stored is less than 2Gb (potentially a lot less), since WiredTiger is not available and MMAPv1 is limited to a maximum file size of 2Gb since it makes heavy use of memory-mapping. It simply has a very limited addressable space on 32-bit machines
- The WiredTiger storage engine is not available. It allows compression and hence would be especially interesting for limited resources.
- MongoDB needs RAM. The more, the better. Indexes need it, connections need it desperately, and hm, the *memory* mapping makes good use of it. And well, we are only on 32bits. MongoDB Inc decided against creating workarounds for a dying technology. So do not expect this to change
- The biggest drawback, however, is that journaling and replication are basically No-Gos since the further limit the amount of data you can store. No journaling translates to limited durability of your data (unless you are willing to force the data to be synced to disk for each write by using an according write concern), while the lack of replication and the resulting lack of failover capabilities most likely is less of a concern on a Raspi.

MongoDB Inc strongly advises against using the 32-bit version for other than testing purposes. And they do so for a good reason. Personally, my generated test data by far exceeds the limitations of the 32-bit version.

So yes, it should be technically possible (and even with no package at hand: compiling MongoDB is no rocket science). Is it a good idea? Well, not so much, if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. Limitations are high but it’s for testing purpose, I use mongodb because, my fontend app written in react and I need to retrieve JSON files to render the components with the data, I think mongodb was best suited instead of using mysql with ORM like sequelize. It's a chat app using socket io clients write in the database frequently and retrieve the messages on web browser reload. Redis is not suited for that i do not know how much data will be stored. What database would you use on a raspberry pi ? I use raspberry pi to test my app before buying a mini-PC

Comment: Don't use a database for integration, use Linux sockets instead for sending protocoll buffer based messages. Back to the roots! If you don't need a DBMS server, SQLite works extremely well and is resource friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i will look Linux sockets more in details. For SQLite i seed that it doesn't handle the concurrency. So in chat app i decided to exclude it. 
Using a database that differs to the final product, you have to rewrite the app and add more testing, so I look into restrictions of mongodb, the 1Gb size left is enough for me for testing. Concerning the journaling I see that mongo asks the OS to flush in-memory changes. So I will do some backup throws sh for data corruption. Thank again for you advise, next time I will check on os/architecture before buying a cheap product.

Comment: @user3343399 If it is only for testing purposes, there should not be much of a problem. Journaling is only for durability of data changes, which should not be much of a thing in a test environment. Speaking of that: VPS are that cheap nowadays, I don't see the point in buying metal for tests at all. Regarding concurrency for SQLite: It does not handle concurrency itself, that is correct. But nobody prevents you to wrap a mutex around the operations.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the blog http://www.clarenceho.net/2015/12/building-mongodb-30x-for-arm-armv7l.html mentioned by @user3343399

Just to add that Arch Linux ARM latest build of MongoDB 3.2.0 seems to be working fine. Except that the default storage engine was compiled as WiredTiger although there is no 32-bit support from WiredTiger.  You will need to add parameter --storageEngine=mmapv1

Comment: Thank again your blog was really helpful !

Comment: AFAIK, MongoDB starting v3.2 uses SpiderMonkey engine instead V8, so i have a question: as for v3.2+ there is no more any need to patch any sources?